# How to minimize my desktop Flutter app to system tray?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I am building a Flutter desktop application and I would like to leave the app running on the system tray instead of just closing it.

Answer (score 2):

##### With help of [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) you can hide the window instead of closing it.

in main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Must add this line.
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();

  WindowOptions windowOptions = WindowOptions(
    size: Size(800, 600),
    center: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    skipTaskbar: false,
    titleBarStyle: TitleBarStyle.hidden,
  );
  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow(windowOptions, () async {
    await windowManager.show();
  });

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

To Hide the app window for MacOS, **return false** on **applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed**
import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
     return false
  }
}
```

call **windowManager.hide()** when you want to hide the window.

call **windowManager.show()** when you want to show the window

```
void _hideWindow() {
  windowManager.hide() // will hide the window and the app will be running in the background
}

void _showWindow() {
  windowManager.show() // will show the window
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While working on for your query, I found the following links that might be helpful

https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/issues/595

https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/%EF%B8%8F-the-tricky-task-of-keeping-flutter-running-on-android-2d51bbc60882

The descriptive/precise documentation is still in progress for the flutter team itself. Many more features to be included soon.

Comment: Found a solution on this yet? Im also looking

Comment: The second link is related to Android, not the desktop.

The first link describes tray functionality, which is implementable via Flutter packages already. It doesn't go into closing a window while keeping the app running.